# How to save the map as jpg format

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now ROS saves the robot map as pgm format,  but I want to save the map as jpg format, I konw I could use the opencv  to convert the "pgm map" to the "jpg map",  but if I could save the map as jpg format in the map_saver code directly, it would be better. However, I know little about picture format and it's difficult for me to write the code by myself.

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223895/how-to-save-the-map-as-jpg-format/) by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, I'd advise against saving the map as .jpg as that introduces compression artifacts that look bad and can mess with further processing (or the eye of the beholder ;) ).

If you absolutely want to directly save the map as jpg, the easiest way is probably to copy/modify the map_saver, add a dependency on opencv, convert the map to a cv::Mat in the map callback and then write it out as jpg. [Here is code for converting a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid to cv::Mat](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/mapstitch/blob/hector_mapstitch/src/utils.cpp#L5) and [here is an example of saving a cv::Mat to jpg](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html).

A easier option is of course to use a command-line tool such as [convert](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_convert.htm). It should allow to perform the conversion from command line or inside a script by simply calling

```
convert map.pgm map.jpg
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tanghz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21137/tanghz/) on 2016-01-12**:
Thank you very much!